# Adobe flash CC Unable to select other text type other than dynamic text

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cc

[image: Screenshot of the program]

Hi guys, i am facing problems with the adobe flash program, currently the input and static text is greyed out.

Any advice? as dynamic text does not allow users to enter after exporting.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are working in the new HTML Canvas document type for Flash CC. These features are greyed out because they are not available in this document file type. You need to create an ActionScript 3 Fla document type and these features will be enabled.

To do this go to file from the pull down menu pick New and select ActionScript 3 for the document type. It is right below HTML Canvas.